# jQuery validation alert issue

Tags: javascript, validation

I am new to javascript and having hard time validating my form.

I have a from where I am asking questions from customer. There are 2 required question (range ones), I have already set requiredQuestions array in a loop which is referenced in javascript so as to validate only required questions)

Here is my form code:

```
 <form id="frmQuestion" method="post">
 <input type="range" id="#QuestionID# name="#QuestionID#" min="0" max="10">
 <textarea cols="40" rows="10" name="#QuestionDomID#" id="#QuestionDomID#"    </textarea>
  <input type="button" value="submit" id="frmQuestion_submit">
 </form>
```

And here is the javascript:

```
 <cfoutput>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('##frmQuestion_submit').click(function()
    {
        var jsArr;
        var jsArr = #SerializeJson(requiredQuestions)#;
        for(var i=0;i<jsArr.length;i++){
            var question = jsArr[i].FNAME;
            var qValue = $("##QuestionID#").val();

            if (qValue == 0){
                alert('Please fill all required fields');
                return false;
            }
            else{
            return true;
            }

        }

    });
</script>
```

I only want to alert once but here it is alerting twice - one for each question. If i add return false, its not alerting if first question is answered.

Comment: Please get rid of all the double hashtags in your jQuery

Comment: Oh I did that because am using ColdFusion as server side language and I have cfoutput

Comment: Your HTML is pretty broken too. If it's running at all right now then the browser is just being super nice. You also don't have an element called `frmQuestion_submit` so you can't really bind to an event on it. Consider setting up a `submit` handler on the form instead. Fix your HTML first then hit those other problems.

Comment: Done, sorry, its my bad, its just typing a part of code so broken html,i added the submit event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through all of your array and set a flag indicating an error condition if one is found.  After the loop executes, check the flag and act accordingly.

```
var validationFailed = false;
for(var i=0;i<jsArr.length;i++){
        var question = jsArr[i].FNAME;
        var qValue = $("##QuestionID#").val();

        if (qValue == 0){
            validationFailed = true;
        }
}
if (validationFailed)
{
   alert('Please fill all required fields');
   return false;
}
else
{
   return true;
}
```

Comment: This worked for a part but it now keeps alerting the message and won't ever return true

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening in your code that checks the value but probably the code you supplied is not properly checking the values.  Are you sure that `.val()` would be a number comparable to 0?  My guess is that it won't be.  Did you mean to check `qValue.length`?  I assume that you also meant to do something with the `question` variable otherwise it seems useless.  did you mean to do `qValue = $("#" + question).val()`?

Comment: Ya, I change the questionID to question from requiredQuestions Array, that worked, thanks!